# How to create a video call app in nativescript

Tags: webrtc, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I'm trying to add videocall feature to my nativescript app
i already found [Nativescript-webrtc](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc) plugin, but its giving me errors on `Nativescript core js`, there's a demo but its `nativescript core ts`. I spoke to the plugin author about it, he said he'll look into it, so I'm waiting for him

*This is my [conversation](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc/issues/30) with the plugin author, I'm Adekunle11*

But time is not on my side, so I'm looking for other options

Please, if there's anyone who has worked with the videocall feature on nativescript (preferrably nativescript-core), i would appreciate if you could walk me through it.

Thanks in Advance